# Writing assembly in C++ without using other variables

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, g++, x86-64

I am writing a simple C++ program that includes some asm instructions.

```
void call(){
    __asm__("mov    -0x10(%rbp),%eax;"
            "add    $0x10,%eax;"
            "mov    %eax,%edx;"
            "shr    $0x1f,%edx;"
            "add    %edx,%eax;"
            "sar    %eax;"
            "add    %eax,-0x4(%rbp);"
            "mov    $0x4c,%eax;"
            "mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax;"
            "add    %eax,%eax;"
            "sub    -0x4(%rbp),%eax;"
            "add    %eax,-0xc(%rbp);");
}
```

However, from the execution behavior I realized that registers manipulated by this asm body are actually used by other variables in the function.

Is there anyway to invoke the compiler to isolate the registers used in **asm** tag and make sure they aren't effected?

OS: Linux
Compiler: G++

Non-compiler approaches are also welcome

Comment: This is bad, very bad. This code assumes that variables on the stack are in a specific place. You should be using a [_GCC_ extended assembly template](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) and passing the variables as constraints to the template as to not rely on hard coded locations. As well since you are not using any constraints you are clobbering _EAX_ and _EDX_ which may be used for other purposes. _GCC_ makes no assumptions about your inline assembler (unlike _MASM_ ).

Comment: I'd ask a question. The assembler you have assumes there are local variables on the stack (ie negative displacement from _RBP_) although in the code function `callOne`has no local variables. Is this a complete code snippet of that function or is there more to it? What OS is this for (Windows/Linux/BSD?). And why can't you create C++ code for this? Are you working on an exploit?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I updated the question. Linux, this is the complete function I am using no more codes.

Comment: If this is complete code may I ask where the assembler code you are using came from? It seems like it may have been pulled from other code (disassembled?) and plopped in. I say this because wherever this code came from it originally was part of a function that had a number of local variables (seems like 4 of them from eyeballing the code or possibly fewer if there was an array involved)

Comment: @MichaelPetch indeed part of a previously compiled code. At the moment I don't care about the result, rather about whether the code runs or not. So it could be manipulating junk addresses and I don't mind.

Comment: I'm not advocating this as an answer, it is still fraught with issues (like using stack variables and then potentially clobbering the redzone) and if this was inlined with the optimizer it may still fail because there may be no stack frame pointer (RPB isn't even a valid memory address). If your intent is to tell GCC that you are clobbering _RAX_ and _RDX_ and not assume their values are the same after the `__asm__` block then you can add them as clobbers. Last line of asm block could be `"add    %eax,-0xc(%rbp);" ::: "rax", "rdx");`

Comment: As well to add those clobbers as suggested in my last comment then the template becomes extended (instead of basic) and all the register names have to have 2 `%` in front of them instead of one. (`%eax` would become `%%eax` etc)

Comment: *" I don't care about the result, rather about whether the code runs or not"* = but that's the same thing. Accessing invalid memory will crash it, so make it "not run", but if the address is accidentally valid, it will run with garbage results.. I don't see how that is different for you. In either case this code you posted will need lot of rewrite first to make some sense in 64b C++ project. You can basically just delete it (as it is not doing anything significant toward C++ part of code), and the code will run better than now, without some rogue asm instructions modifying some random memory.

Comment: And whatever meaning/significance that code had in old 32b executable is already lost, so if your code is not working as expected after deleting this asm block, then it will not work as expected even with this asm block. You would first need to figure out, what was it purpose in original code, and then rewrite that purpose in your new code, instead of copying the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

As a non-compiler approach: you could use `pusha`/`popa` instructions to push all the registers to the stack before execution of your own assembly and pop all of them afterwards.

Code example:

```
void callOne(){
    __asm__(
        "pusha;"
        "mov    -0x10(%rbp),%eax;"
        "add    $0x10,%eax;"
        "mov    %eax,%edx;"
        "shr    $0x1f,%edx;"
        "add    %edx,%eax;"
        "sar    %eax;"
        "add    %eax,-0x4(%rbp);"
        "mov    $0x4c,%eax;"
        "mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax;"
        "add    %eax,%eax;"
        "sub    -0x4(%rbp),%eax;"
        "add    %eax,-0xc(%rbp);"
        "popa;");
}
```

Comment: @Syntax_Error Oops. Maybe there're some similar instructions.

Comment: @Syntax_Error `pusha` is "undefined" in 64b mode, to do the same thing just `push/pop` all individual registers which you modify , actually just two of them [ `push rax` `push rdx` ... your code ... `pop rdx` `pop rax` ]. Or [learn](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) how to mark that block of assembly to be "clobbering" `rax` and `rdx` (I myself don't know as I don't use inline assembly, so no example from me). (this of course expects you actually do **want** to modify `[rbp-16]`, `[rbp-8]` and `[rbp-4]`, which are some local function variables)

Comment: Thinking about it, you must tell about usage/modification of those local variables back to C++ compiler too, so you are probably "doing it wrong", the inline assembly is quite tricky to get right. Either do this as standalone function so it will follow the calling ABI, or you will have to learn all the details of inline assembly and the extended definitions to explain compiler, what is happening inside that string (compiler has no idea, what that string of assembly is doing), ie. what it needs available and what it does modify. Ultimately just rewrite that in C++, it's easy + better code.

Comment: @Ped7g : If the Linux 64-bit System V ABI is being adhered to (may not be the case because of course the OP didn't mention what OS) I'd be careful about pushing and popping in a template because you may also have to take into account that the redzone may be in play.

Comment: @Syntax_Error oh, as Michael warns, it's even more tricky, even my "fix" **is wrong** and will work only by accident. So in 64b either learn how to do all that inline-asm marking stuff to explain the compiler what that block does, or create standalone asm function, modified to follow your ABI, and call it as standalone.

Answer (score 1):

inline assembly is heavily compiler specific, most of the work is the compiler nuances, yes you can tell the compiler to avoid conflict with other registers used by copmiled code and/or you can interact with the high level language variables and pull those into the inline assembly.  But it is very much compiler specific.  If you want a whole function in assembly then just make an assembly function and avoid the compiler issues.  An easy place to start is prototype the function in C/C++, compile it to asm or disassemble then use that as your skeleton for your asm function.

Answer (score 1):

`asm()` [as defined in the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm) is really just a way to enable individual compilers to "slot in" their implementation's solution into the language. From the point-of-view of the standard, anything within `asm()` is "here be dragons" and not specified any further.

One implementation-defined solution for inline assembly is [GCC's Extended ASM](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) statement (not-so-coincidentially following the `asm()` form), which allows (actually, *requires*...) you to specify which variables go in, which ones go out, and which ones get clobbered, allowing the compiler -- which is otherwise ignorant of what your ASM source code *does* -- to do "the right thing" with regards to cached values, optimizations etc.

The [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly) has a somewhat more accessible introduction to GCC's inline assembly syntax, including a couple of (OS-kernel-related) [examples](http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples).

---

Microsoft has its own flavor of [Inline Assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93(v=vs.120).aspx) (and, quite typical, does *not* play nicely with `asm()` but insists on `__asm()`, and indeed also insists on you saving / restoring any registers manually.

Comment: _MASM_ is far more forgiving (relatively speaking) since in 32-bit code (inline assembly not available in 64-bit) you don't need to preserve EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, or EDI registers across an asm block. You can use them to your hearts content. This is one reason why _MASM_ does a worse job optimizing around inline assembler. Of course inline assembler should be used sparingly (or at all) and if you can using compiler intrinsics would be preferred (or just code the function in an external assembler object)

Comment: When I said MASM I meant MSVC/MSVC++